# java.sql.Date is deprecated what should I use?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to use to insert a date to my sqlite database.

```
public CardHolder(String firstName, String lastName, String barcodeNb,
                         Date dateOfBirth,Date expiryDate)
```

Where I initiated this instance in the mainActivity

```
 CardHolder person1 =new CardHolder("John","example","123123",new
                    java.sql.Date(1993,9,3),new java.sql.Date(1993,9,3));
```

But it shows that java.sql.Date is deprecated, what should I use instead?

Comment: Date isn't deprecated, but the constructor you are using is. I would recommend looking at the javadoc for the class and picking another way of constructing your Date objects

Comment: see here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887653/jdbc-dates-deprecated-in-java-java-sql-package you find your solution here

Comment: @beresfordt I want to save the date in a specific format( any known format date) not in Milliseconds

Comment: @RimaHajou `new java.sql.Date(60707833200000L)` produces an object which is equal to `new java.sql.Date(1993,9,3)`; it is just a different method of construction. It is worth noting that `new java.sql.Date(1993,9,3)` does not do what you think it does.. You should read the javadoc

Answer (score 1):

```
new java.sql.Date(new GregorianCalendar(1993, 9, 3).getTimeInMillis())
```

Comment: I want to save it in a date format

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).